# Use of unresolved identifier 'NSCollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical'

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, cocoa

Weird error on something that seems like it should be simple.

I have an NSCollectionView with an NSCollectionViewFlowLayout (called flowLayout) that was running fine, but it was a multi-column layout and I wanted it to be a single-column layout. So [it seemed](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSCollectionViewFlowLayout_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSCollectionViewFlowLayout/scrollDirection) like I should just add a simple command to do this:

```
flowLayout.scrollDirection = NSCollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical
```

But when I added this command I got this error: "Use of unresolved identifier 'NSCollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical'". I was already importing Cocoa but thought I might need to import AppKit. So I now import both Cocoa and AppKit but I still get this error; Xcode really thinks NSCollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical is not a thing even though the documentation tells me it should be.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSCollectionViewFlowLayout_class/#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSCollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical) suggested to me further that since it was an enum value within NSCollectionViewScrollDirection, maybe I should add a dot so it is

```
flowLayout.scrollDirection = NSCollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical
```

I tried that version and no longer got an error - it just didn't do anything at all, the scroll direction was still horizontal. :-/ What am I missing?

Comment: I suspect you want to change `maxNumberOfColumns`, not `scrollDirection`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, just tried that now. Two problems with it: 1. maxNumberOfColumns appears to be a [legacy feature](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCollectionView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSCollectionView/maxNumberOfColumns), so it's not the ideal solution. 2. It still doesn't work: the build fails with the error "Value of type 'NSCollectionFlowLayout' has no member 'maxNumberOfColumns'".

Comment: Sorry, you're right, that's a property from before the FlowLayout class existed. You should probably just adjust the item size and inter-item spacing so that the items are forced to be 1 per row rather than wrapping and forming multiple columns.

Comment: Thanks... I thought of that, it just seemed a little kludgey. It's also kind of bugging me that NSCollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical gives me an error, since the documentation says it should work. Surely this isn't just a bug in Swift, there's something I'm missing on thatpoint?

Comment: Are you looking at an Obj-C example or a Swift example?

Comment: Swift, only Swift. The [documentation I linked to](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSCollectionViewFlowLayout_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSCollectionViewFlowLayout/scrollDirection) says it is Swift, and all my code is in Swift - I don't know Obj-C.

Comment: *I tried that version and no longer got an error - it just didn't do anything at all, the scroll direction was still vertical.* I'm not sure what you mean by this - isn't this the behavior you're after?

Comment: Paul: D'oh. Mistyped that (and just edited it now): I meant it was still horizontal, as in, expanding the window moved the items into additional columns, which is what I'm trying to get it not to do. I want it all to be in one single column, irrespective of window width.

Comment: It's a bit of a long shot, but you could try ``flowLayout.scrollDirection = NSCollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical.rawValue``.

Comment: Just tried that. New error: "Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'NSCollectionViewScrollDirection'." Looks like we do still need the original Vertical type... that Xcode doesn't seem to recognize. Have I found a bug?